# how to make a function call other 4 functions to perform 4 arithmetic operation (addition, subtraction, multiplication and division)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm finding hard to call other functions. For example, if the user input `calculate(2,3,"+")` i want to call the `addition()` function and show the result. if the user input `calculate(2,3,"-")` i want to call the `subtraction()` function.
this is my code

```
def addition():
if string == "+":
    a = num1 + num2
    print("addition was performed on the two numbers ", num1, ' and ', num2)
    return a



def subtraction():
if string == "-":
    s = num1 - num2
    print("subtraction was performed on the two numbers ", num1, ' and ', num2)
    return s



def multiplication():
if string == "*":
    t = num1 * num2
    print("multiplication was performed on the two numbers ", num1, ' and ', num2)
    return t



def division():
if string == "/":
    d = num1 / num2
    print("division was performed on the two numbers ", num1, ' and ', num2)
    return d


def calculate(num1, num2, string):
str(string)
```

I want the `calculate(num1, num2, string)` to call the other functions.
by the way im beginner sorry if my code make you confused

**Thanks, domandinho. The if spaces got messed up when I pasted the code here, cheers **

Comment: First things first: Fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have wrong intendation. if instruction should be after 4 spaces, all instructions under if should be after 8 spaces. All variables should be accessible for functions which are using them, so addition, subtraction, multiplication and division needs num1 and num2 as arguments.
str(string) do nothing, because type of string variable is str. You must call these 4 functions in calculate function, depending on value of string.

Secondly if which checks value of str should be in calculate function, not in for example addition function. Addition function will return None if string will be other than '+'.

```
def addition(num1, num2):
    a = num1 + num2
    print("addition was performed on the two numbers ", num1, ' and ', num2)
    return a


def subtraction(num1, num2):
    s = num1 - num2
    print("subtraction was performed on the two numbers ", num1, ' and ', num2)
    return s


def multiplication(num1, num2):
    t = num1 * num2
    print("multiplication was performed on the two numbers ", num1, ' and ', num2)
    return t


def division(num1, num2):
    d = num1 / num2
    print("division was performed on the two numbers ", num1, ' and ', num2)
    return d


def calculate(num1, num2, string):
    result = None
    if string == '+':
        result = addition(num1, num2)
    elif string == '-':
        result = subtraction(num1, num2)
    elif string == '*':
        result = multiplication(num1, num2)
    elif string == '/':
        result = division(num1, num2)
    print('Result is ' + str(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using a dictionary and the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

```
import operator

d = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
    }

def calculate(num1, num2, string):
    return d[string](num1, num2)
```